# Edit regular expression to support + (plus) notation

Tags: regex

I'm using a regex to 'quick and dirty' validate an email address client side and I just found out it doesn't support the `+` plus notation (`user+anything@gmail.com`) google provides its users.  I'm sure it fails in other points as well.  How can I edit this to support `+` notation and ensure I'm dealing with an email address while not pissing anyone with an oddly formed email address off?

```
`var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]`{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
```

**Word wrapped:**

```
var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
```

Thank you,

Comment: As a side note, the *"gmail's + (plus) notation"* was a standard email feature provided by `sendmail` (and other SMTP servers) at least 10 years before Gmail was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your regular expression and removed an extra parenthesis and is working fine to me:

```
^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+))|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)))(@((?:[\w-]+.)*\w[\w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@[?((25[0-5].|2[0-4][0-9].|1[0-9]{2}.|[0-9]{1,2}.)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}).){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})]?$
```

Live demo:

https://regex101.com/r/kX3jW0/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:[.+][\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:[.+][\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)
```

It's still quick and dirty.  It will allow your example `user+anything@gmail.com`, but will also allow `user+anything+else@gmail.com`.  It won't allow for `user++anything@gmail.com` or `user.+anything@gmail.com`.